# Generating private key with guid in Open SSL

Tags: openssl, key, guid, private-key

I want to generate keys using openSSL with following attributes. I searched online to know the correct syntax but no results.

Create a JWK keyset (using OpenSSL, etc.) with one or more keys, with the following attributes for each
key:
Encryption Algorithm: RS384
Key Use: Signature
Key Size: 3072 or 4096 bits
Key ID MUST be a GUID (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

Please let me know on how to get it done.

Thanks